# list packages and check signature

Tags: android, security, adb

I have connected to my android phone via adb shell and have a list of all apps installed with

```
pm list packages
```

Is there any way to check the signature of the installed package and compare it with google play or something to know if that app is original or it can be hacked?

Best regards

Comment: Signatures are checked by Android at installation time. It caches the information in a central XML file (don't remember the path, but AFAIR it was only accessible on rooted devices). If you really want to check the APK signatures you need to download the APK signatures and process them using apksigner from Android SDK. Not sure if you can execute apksigner.jar on Android side in an adb shell, never tried it.